# The issue is I could not connect to scylla nodes from my python app. Should I need to change any scylla.yaml properties?

Tags: docker, scylla

I just started to explore on ScyllaDB for using in our application. I could spin up the scylla in my local docker. The issue is I could not connect to any of these from my python app. Should I need to change any scylla.yaml properties?

```
$ docker exec -it scylla1 nodetool status
Datacenter: datacenter1
=======================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address     Load       Tokens       Owns    Host ID                               Rack
UN  172.17.0.3  148.85 KB  256          ?       a93f8715-ff4c-43f4-8ee3-f28f936aa842  rack1
UN  172.17.0.2  158.58 KB  256          ?       c34446ca-4b11-48a6-b329-db73fd22e059  rack1
UN  172.17.0.4  146.81 KB  256          ?       4b13b043-3422-4589-b829-c26a48e7fb6e  rack1
```

Python App:

```
class App:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cluster = Cluster(contact_points=["scylla1", "scylla2", "scylla3"])
        # self.cluster = Cluster(contact_points=["172.17.0.2", "172.17.0.3", "172.17.0.4"])
        self.session = self.cluster.connect(keyspace="catalog")
        self.session.default_consistency_level = ConsistencyLevel.QUORUM



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
```

Comment: Look like a Docker networking issues.
Try using the IPs, not the docker instances names.

Comment: https://university.scylladb.com/courses/scylla-essentials-overview/ is a good resource for getting started and includes setting up a local Docker running Scylla. 
More advanced topics on Docker and performance are at https://docs.scylladb.com/operating-scylla/procedures/tips/best_practices_scylla_on_docker/

Answer (score 1):

It's probably because you run the container without port mapping. Add -p 9042:9042 and you'll be able to access it. Always check with telnet or cqlsh